# How to delete nodes other than those defined in the array using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am new to using `Linq to Xml`, so my problem probably is very easy to solve.

**First Question:**
I want to remove all nodes except those whose names i have already in array using Linq.

**Second Question:**
How to check, that node field, has three childnodes (name,type,value), and remove those field, whose don't meet requirement?

I have already done, removing empty nodes, but for this problems i don't have ideas.

Thank you in advance!

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
           xml.Descendants().Where(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value)).Remove();

           ArrayList permitted = new ArrayList { "object", "obj_name", "name", "field", "value", "type" };




HERE SOME XML OF THIS.
<object>
<obj_name>wolf</obj_name>
<field>
<name>color</name>
<type>string</type>
<value>grey</value>
</field>
<lolfield>lol"</lolfield> //for example this should be removed//
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using contains like this:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        xml.Descendants().Where(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value)).Remove();

        ArrayList permitted = new ArrayList { "object", "obj_name", "name", "field", "value", "type" };

        xml.Descendants().Where(e => permitted.Contains(e.Value)).Remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** The following code will mark for deletion any xml elements that have an empty value or have a name contained in the Array:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
ArrayList permitted = new ArrayList { "object", "obj_name", "name", "field", "value", "type" };
xml.Descendants().Where(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value) || !permitted.Contains(e.Name.ToString().ToLower())).Remove();
```

`e.Name.ToString()` will return the full name of the element including both the namespace and the local name. If only the local name is desired for comparison, then use `e.Name.LocalName` instead.

**2.** And this will specifically target any "field" elements and make sure they contain only the requested three names (no duplicates):

```
ArrayList permittedInField = new ArrayList { "name", "value", "type" };
foreach (XElement elField in xml.Descendants("field"))
    elField.Descendants().Where((e) => !permittedInField.Contains(e.Name.ToString().ToLower()) || 
        e.Parent.Elements().Any((o) => string.Equals(e.Name.ToString(), o.Name.ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && e.IsAfter(o)))
        .Remove();
```